# AttributeError at /akolaprofile/ 'MyRegistration' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to create a user profile by using Django's **UserChangeForm**. I'm not using Django's User model and had created a custom user model **(MyRegistration)** by inheriting **AbstractBaseUser**. I have also assigned my custom user model to **AUTH_USER_MODEL** in the settings.py. But when I try to access the user's profile page, it throws an **AttributeError** stating that **'MyRegistration' object has no attribute 'get'**. What could possibly be wrong?
Below are my codes:

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils import timezone
from .manager import FirstManager

class MyRegistration(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    location_list=[
        ('Solapur', 'Solapur'),
        ('Latur', 'Latur'),
        ('Dhule', 'Dhule'),
        ('Akola', 'Akola'),
        ('Nashik', 'Nashik')
        ]
    username=models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=location_list, default='Latur')
    designation=models.CharField(max_length=70)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    start_date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(null=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD='username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'location', 'designation']
    objects=FirstManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**views.py**:

```
def akolaprofile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        print(request.user)
        fm=UserChangeForm(request.user)
        return render(request, 'akola/akolaprofile.html', {'form':fm})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

**URLs**:

```
path('akolaprofile/', ve.akolaprofile, name='akolaprofile'),
```

**Template**:

```
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

**Traceback**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Sonu\Projects\Billing\accounting\akola\views.py", line 21, in akolaprofile
    return render(request, 'akola/akolaprofile.html', {'form':fm})
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 988, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 671, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 796, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 858, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 290, in as_p
    return self._html_output(
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 193, in _html_output
    top_errors = self.non_field_errors().copy()
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 304, in non_field_errors
    return self.errors.get(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, self.error_class(error_class='nonfield'))
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 170, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 372, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 384, in _clean_fields
    value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 263, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)
  File "C:\Users\pande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 247, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /akolaprofile/
Exception Value: 'MyRegistration' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Show your code for `UserChangeForm`.

Comment: I directly wrote the view to display the built-in UserChangeForm. I have posted the code in views.py here. I did not create a separate form for this. Do I need to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of your form is normally the `data`, the second the `files`. You probably want to use `request.user` as instance, you do this by passing it with:

```
def akolaprofile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        fm=UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
        return render(request, 'akola/akolaprofile.html', {'form':fm})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: @noob87 Other than this the `UserChangeForm` should also be changed if it is the default one from `auth`, since that uses the builtin user model from auth. You should inherit from it and set the model in its `Meta`.

Comment: Yes, I just did that! Thanks buddy! :)